# Difference between approxCountDsitinct and approx_count_distinct in spark functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Can anyone tell the difference between `pyspark.sql.functions.approxCountDistinct` (I know it is deprecated) and `pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct`? I have used both versions in a project and have experienced different values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned it, `pyspark.sql.functions.approxCountDistinct` is deprecated. The reason is most likely just a style concern. They probably wanted everything to be in snake case. As you can see in [the source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#approxCountDistinct) `pyspark.sql.functions.approxCountDistinct` simply calls `pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct`, nothing more except giving you a warning. So regardless the one you use, the very same code runs in the end.

Also, still according to the source code, `approx_count_distinct` is based on the [HyperLogLog++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog#HLL++) algorithm. I am not very familiar with the algorithm but it is based on repetitive set merging. Therefore, the result will most likely depend on the order in which the various results of the executors are merged. Since this is not deterministic with spark, this could explain why you witness different results.

Comment: Thank you for that, Also do you think approx_count_distinct is deterministic?

Comment: And the answer to your question is most likely no.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I cant accept it since I have a new account,, but highly appreciate it

Comment: If you are allowed to ask a question, you can accept the answer to it ;-), Just click on the V like button that's right under the triangle used to downvote answers. You can also upvote the answer if you feel like it.